# How can I reduce the time of a MySQL O(n^2) query?

Tags: mysql, facebook

Trying to run this query to find the intersection of two sets (users who post on one page and users who post on another). Unfortunately, this takes ridiculous amounts of time to complete (10+ minutes). Is there any way to reduce its complexity?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (user_id) 
FROM facebook_post_comments 
WHERE page_id = some_page_id 
AND user_id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) 
                 FROM facebook_post_comments 
                 WHERE page_id = some_other_page_id )
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? `select version();`

Comment: Hey Mark, I'm running 5.5.14.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32665) in MySQL where IN with a subquery sometimes gives very poor performance (fixed in MySQL 5.6).

Try this query using a `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM facebook_post_comments T1 
JOIN facebook_post_comments T2
    ON T1.user_id = T2.user_id
    AND T2.page_id = some_other_page_id
WHERE T1.page_id = some_page_id
```

Comment: +1 For the same answer I was going to posit, 6 seconds before I posited it.

Comment: This query takes a tenth of the time to run and that's without page_id being indexed. Going to look into upgrade to 5.6 when I have couple extra minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Adding the index will almost certainly give a huge improvement.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful if you provided some idea of what your database schema looks like, but if this is taking 10+ minutes, I'm going to guess the problem is that you don't have indexes on the page_id column.  Try adding an index and re-running that query.

Answer (score 0):

If `user_id` is not indexed, using the `DISTINCT` attribute causes the query to sort the results and this would have O(N^2)-like performance.  Is `DISTINCT` really needed?

Comment: In this particular case DISTINCT is needed. I only want to be able to quantify is a user has participated on page_id 1 and page_id 2, not necessarily count the number of interactions. Does that make sense?